# How can blackholes be fast information scramblers?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I noticed that there was already a [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33377/what-is-the-mechanism-for-fast-scrambling-of-information-by-black-holes) discussing the fast scrambling property of black holes. But it seems no satisfactory answer was given.

As mentioned by L. Susskind et. al, the fast scrambling property of BHs seems to say BHs are infinite dimensional systems so that every pair of qubits can directly interact 'locally' so that the fast scrambling can be implemented by BHs. He also mentioned that this is due to the effect of gravity during the collapse procedure.

I am wondering, how such a gravitational collapse can lead to such an 'infinite dimensional' geometry? If the geometry is related with tensor networks, then what's the correspondent tensor network of BHs? It sounds very strange for me.

An alternative is that maybe we do not need such an 'infinite dimensional' geometry, instead if the *internal* geometry of BHs is a manifold with a vanishing geodesic distance as discussed [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409303v2), then the fast scrambling assumption may also be valid. But still, how such a geometry can be built inside a BH? Also, it seems that such a vanishing geodesic manifold should be an infinite dimensional manifold.