# What is the fast scrambling conjecture?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement

What is fast scrambling in context of black hole?

Comment: What do you need to know that the answers in the related questions list do not tell you ?

Comment: See the Introduction of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6580).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33377/2451